# YouTube API- retrieve all comments text on each video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using YouTube API to fetch user feed and all video details.

Eg : Number of likes,number of dislikes.etc. Number of comments on video is correct but while I am fetching all the comments data found nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some example code, or just the URLs that you're accessing, so that we could help debug what's going on.

Comment: i am using this "var url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' + usname + '?v=2&alt=json';" to fetch youtube user feed. And to fetch comments data am using this"var commn_url = http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + cmnt_video_id + '/comments?v=2&alt=json';".Number of comments count is correct,but there is no data for those comments.

Answer (score 2):

The correct URL to request is http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/`VIDEO_ID`/comments?v=2 (with any other parameters you want).

E.g. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/fhWaJi1Hsfo/comments?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true returns the comments feed for video id `fhWaJi1Hsfo`, and I do see the content of the actual comments in that feed.

If you're not able to successfully reproduce that with a specific video id, could you let us know which video you're having trouble with?

Comment: thanks for reply..
Yes..I am using this 
URL(http://http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments?v=2 ) to fetch comments feed.For some video-ids it's working fine.But in some cases there is comment count but no comment feed..

E.g.http://http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Kmfoh2Ut3Ts/comments?v=2&alt=json returns no comment feed for this video id.

Comment: I don't see any comments listed in the web interface either: http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=Kmfoh2Ut3Ts

Comment: But it gives comment count = 1("openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":1}).

Any idea why its showing this,while there is no comment data..

Comment: I don't know. But since the API isn't returning any results and the web interface isn't returning any results, I think it's safe to say that there are no results.